# BinSize in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

i am trying to plot the distribution of P values in ggplot but i am unable to

decide how can i choose correct bin size

when i used bin size 30 on my data  i cant show min and
 max values and not all bins and binwidth.

```
min = 1.885e-15
max= 1.078e-05
```

my code is

```
x = read.table("11-20.txt", sep=" ", header=F)
library(ggplot2)

min(x$V10)
max(x$V10)

ggplot(x, aes(V10)) + 
 geom_histogram(color="black", fill="yellow") +
 xlab("minP of every test")
```

how can i show minimum and maximum with clear bin size

[image]

Comment: Consider plotting `log10(p-value)` instead?

Comment: i did but it doesnt improve much